# Resources for learning how to design a multi-process software and how to decide which approach to use

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, process, architecture, multiprocess

I'd like to learn how to decide which approach to multi-process design to use in my software, e.g. how to decide if I should use a daemonized process with client processes connecting on demand, a parent-child processes connected all the time, or any other pattern relevant to multi-process design.

I searched for resources but couldn't find anything satisfying.

Thanks!